# Fast SQL search and sort without temporary tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables.

Tab1:

```
+------------+
| id | title |
+------------+
| 1 | B      |
| 2 | C      |
| 3 | A      |
| 4 | A      |
| 5 | A      |
| 6 | A      |
| ...        |
+------------+
```

PK: ID
Index: title

Tab2:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| id | item_id | item_key |     item_value  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1       | value    | $4              |
| 2  | 1       | url      | http://h.com/   |
| 3  | 2       | value    | $5              |
| 4  | 3       | url      | http://i.com/   |
| 5  | 3       | value    | $1              |
| 6  | 3       | url      | http://y.com/   |
| 7  | 4       | value    | $2              |
| 8  | 4       | url      | http://z.com/   |
| 9  | 5       | value    | $1              |
| 10 | 5       | url      | http://123.com/ |
| ...                                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

PK: id
Index: item_id, item_key

- item_id is a foreign key from tab1.

How do I make it so I get a table of ids from Tab1 in order according to criteria from both tables. The criteria are the following:

- Order ASC by title. If title is the same,
- Order DESC by value. If both title and value is the same,
- Prioritize items who's 'url' key contains '123.com'.

The resulting table with the ordered results would be:

```
+------------+
| id | title |
+------------+
| 4 | A      |
| 5 | A      |
| 3 | A      |
| 6 | A      |
| 1 | B      |
| 2 | C      |
| ...        |
+------------+
```

I know I can do it with:

```
SELECT Tab1.id, Tab1.title
FROM Tab1
JOIN Tab2 t2_val ON t2_val.item_id = Tab1.id AND t2_val.item_key='value'
JOIN Tab2 t2_url ON t2_url.item_id = Tab1.id AND t2_url.item_key='url'
ORDER BY title, 
         t2_val.item_value DESC,
         t2_url.item_value LIKE '%123.com%' DESC
```

but for large data sets, it's too slow. Is there a way to do it faster? I've set index on id and title in Tab 1, and on item key in Tab 2. Now I'd like to drop temporary tables if I could, so that means no joins, right?

How else could this be done?

Comment: Please provide us with some `show create table [table_name]` outputs and some EXPLAIN [your_query] outputs off both tables. .. Your query is prone to wrong table access what may force MySQL optimizer into using an (memory/disk) based temporary table and filesort, most likely the case with an JOIN in combination with ORDER BY query

Answer (score 0):

First, for larger data sets, your result set is going to be larger.  What are you doing with the data afterwards?  The decrease in performance could be primarily related to the data coming out of the database and not to the processing in the database.

Next, what indexes do you have?  The query seems to be begging for an index on `tab2(item_key, item_id)` to resolve the joins.

And, finally, I don't see how you can get around the final sorting for `order by`, because it is using values from both tables.

You are using an "entity-attribute-value" (EAV) model.  This can be inherently slow when choosing lots of columns for lots of records.  If you know that you have these two fields, think about changing the data model so `url` and `value` are columns in `tab1`.

Comment: Changing the db design isn't option sadly. I can introduce indexes, but that's about it. Is there any to order the results without JOINS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title
FROM Tab1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(item_key='value', item_value, '') AS 'value', 
                   MAX(item_key='url', item_value, '') AS 'url'
            FROM Tab2 GROUP BY item_id
           ) t2 ON t2.item_id = t1.id
ORDER BY t1.title, t2.value DESC, IF(t2.url LIKE '%123.com%', 0, 1);
```